# Angular - Is there any performance loss when sending repeated http requests in case the client has internet connection turned off?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from './post.model';
import { PostService } from './post.service';
import {ConnectionService} from 'ng-connection-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  loadedPosts: Post[] = [];
  isFetching = false;
  postCreationData: { name: string };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private postService: PostService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onFetchPosts();
  }

  onFetchPosts() {
      this.isFetching = true;

      this.postService.fetchData().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.loadedPosts = data;
          this.isFetching = false;
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.message);
          this.onFetchPosts();
        }
      );
  }

  onClearPosts() {
    // Send Http request
  }

  onCreatePost(postData: Post) {
      this.isFetching = true;

      this.postService.createPost(postData).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.postCreationData = data;
          console.log(this.postCreationData);
          this.isFetching = false;
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.message);
          this.onFetchPosts();
        }
      );
    }
}
```

Let me explain the code. The `this.postService.fetchData()` method simply sends an http get request to my firebase database. `this.postService.createPost(postData: Post)` sends a post request to the same url with some info on the body. The `isFetching` property allows the app to show a css loading indicator when fetching the data from the server.

Now, I want to show the loading indicator infinitely when the user doesn't have internet connection. Also, at the same time, repeatedly keep sending requests to the server until I get a successfull response in which case, the app simply resumes as it should.

Will there be any noticeable performance loss by doing this. By this, I mean sending infinite number of requests to the server? if so, is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it gives you the interval to make sure it's not impacting performance

```js
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
...

private source = interval(3000); // Allows you to determine how often
...

this.source.subscribe(() => {
  this.httpclient.get('https://www.google.com', { observe: 'response' })
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(resp => {
    if (resp.status === 200 ) {
      //all is good
    } else {
      // some other code like 302,304 etc.
    }
  }, 
  err => { //this is where to process the HTTPErrorResonse  });
});
```

Keep in mind that TCP/IP has auto-retry built-in, up to 10 retries before failure.

Comment: Did this answer help you?